# red color set to row if the date is close to end before 4 months

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a contract program with ms access db in VB, there is a start date and a end date , the row of datagridview should be red before the contract end by 4 months, i have tried some solution but did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows 'look at each row
        'column 1 has dates in my example
        If rw.Cells(1).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If DirectCast(rw.Cells(1).Value, Date) = Date.Now.Date Then
                'met criteria
                rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    Next
```